# Почему Selenium не создает сессию IE, но открывает браузер?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, драйвер, test-automation, rdp

Selenium Server version 3.141.5

IEDriverServer version 3.150.1

Я запускаю на удаленной машине selenium сервер с IE драйвером:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="./iedriver/IEDriverServer.exe" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="./geckodriver/Geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./chromedriver/Chromedriver.exe" -jar ./selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Я захожу на сайт **IP_REMOTE_MACHINE:4444/wd/hub** с локального компьютера и создаю сеанс Internet Explorer, во время создания сеанса я не был подключен к удаленному рабочему столу. Ошибок никаких не появляется. Браузер открывается на удаленном машине, но сессия не создается.

И получается в итоге.

Когда я пытаюсь создать сеанс Internet Explorer, он открывает браузер, но не создает сеанс. Когда я подключаюсь к удаленному рабочему столу и пытаюсь создать сеанс со своего локального компьютера, все происходит успешно. Почему это происходит? Это потому, что сеанс удаленного пользователя не активен? Может из-за того, что удаленный рабочий стол не активен, но тогда почему открывает браузер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как работает Internet Explorer, и от чего это зависит это поведение?

Comment: Странно, что браузер открывается. По идее, когда ремоут десктоп закрыт, то экрана как бы не существует, соотв-но и отображать на нем ничего нельзя. Для таких целей в CI используются "сервисные" польователи от имени которых запускается вся цепочка тестирования. У сервисного юзера есть ассоциированный экран, в который можно всё отображать.

Comment: @AlexeyR. может быть есть какая-нибудь статья того как это можно настроить в ci? Хотя бы примерно.

Comment: Это не про CI, а, скорее про Ваш случай: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461507/running-selenium-server-chromedriver-as-a-windows-service

Comment: @AlexeyR. я только что заметил что иногда в какой-то момент у меня получается запустить сессию нормально, после перезапуска селениума и драйвера, иногда порт поменяю, иногда драйвера в другую папку закину и оттуда их запущу, но это 1 раз из 10 помогает. Однажды, создавало несколько раз сессию, а потом решил проверить и развернуть браузер chrome, и после этого перестал создавать сессию IE. Такое ощущение будто что-то с чем-то конфликтует и после этого он не может корректно создавать сессию.